# Inserting Base64 string into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, encoding, base64

I am building a MVC .NET application. I have a form where a user fills and submits. The form offers to upload a picture. User is presented with an upload screen, the selected photo is cropped and the cropped image is sent to the server in Base64 string format along with other form data.

In the controller, the string is read correctly and I insert the data using Entity Framework. No error is produced up to this stage.

When I open up the related table using the SSMS though, I can see every record in my table except the Base64 string. It does not display NULL either. Just an empty cell.

When I try to manually enter the Base64 text by copying and pasting the **108,537** character long string, I get the well-known "data would be truncated" error. That rang the bell for me to check the data type I am using. So, I tried both `text`, `ntext` and `nvarchar(max)` which produced the same error.

So this now makes me think that my Base64 string is too large however, I that string is generated by the plugin I am using to crop the image. I tried many images in all sort of sizes and obtained similar length strings.

I am wondering what is it that I am doing wrong or what is it that I am not doing at all? Anyone have gone through a similar issue before?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: But why are you **converting** your uploaded image to a Base64 encoded string, thus bloating it up beyond good measure? Why not just store the image as a `varbinary(max)` - a binary data type that's **perfect** for things like images etc.

Comment: Yeah, as @marc_s said you should use `varbinary(max)` to store image as byte array instead of converting it into Base64 string

Comment: Are you sure you want to store the BLOB in a database? It can get very large. I would store the image path in the DB and the image in file system storage. See https://blogs.oracle.com/manveen/entry/blob_vs_file_system_storage

Comment: Project is distributed amongst servers located at different locations hence the file system storage is not an option (unless a custom FTP module is written to put/delete uploaded photos whenever a new one is added or an existing one is deleted) The table will hold maximum of 1000 records so will try the varbinary approach. I still wander the answer to my question though.